# AllowGroup in proftpd not working

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

i want to limit ftp logins to only users from a specific group:
in `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` i have:

```
<Limit LOGIN>
        AllowGroup ftpuser
</Limit>
```

but i can still connect to ftp using a user outside the group:

```
root@packer-debian-7:/etc/proftpd# groups vagrant
vagrant : vagrant cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev
```

login command:

```
root@packer-debian-7:/etc/proftpd# sftp vagrant@localhost
vagrant@localhost's password: 
Connected to localhost.
sftp> dir
kurez  
sftp> quit
```

my whole config file: http://pastebin.com/FWa6TUdv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html):

> Cautious system administrators may want only a few select system users to be able to connect to their proftpd server--all other users are to be denied access. The LOGIN command group is designed for just this scenario:
>
> ```
> <Limit LOGIN>
>   AllowUser barb
>   AllowUser dave
>   AllowGroup ftpuser
>   DenyAll   
> </Limit>
> ```
>
> This allows the users barb and dave, as well as any user in the ftpuser group, to login. All other users will be denied.

You need to use the DenyAll clause right after *AllowGroup ftpuser*